# On Lucas' Theorem over composite

Tags: combinatorics, primality-test

Let p be a composite, and let us apply the simple rule stated by [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) to check whether 
p is prime (that is, involving the p base representation). Now, assume that the result is positive; would that mean that indeed p divides $n \choose k$, or the result is random, since the hypothesis of p being a prime is violated?

Comment: What do you mean by "the simple rule stated by Lucas' theorem"? (I know what you mean, but others might not.)

Comment: "Let $p$ be composite" --- words I thought I'd never see.

Comment: You are asking whether the congruence stated in Lucas's Theorem holds if and only if the modulus is prime, that is, whether Lucas's Theorem can be used as a primality test, the way Wilson's Theorem can?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin He seems to only refer to the special case of Lucas' Theorem where the binomial coefficient is zero, but I guess Qiaochu can help us here after claiming "I know what you mean".